# What's the word for the spanish word "perito" in English?

Tags: word-request, legalese

In Spanish, perito is a person who is an expert in a field, and who plays a role in  trials determining if something happened, if something is true or not , etc. You have peritos who determines if a bullet come from certain gun, if a patient is sane or not, if some data was sent from certain computer, etc. I looked the translator by it gives the words "expert" or "proficient" which seems unrelated to trial procedures.

What's the word for the spanish word "perito" in English?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is off topic. A very quick google for the translation of this returns multiple results [Ex.](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/perito+judicial.html). The one you're probably looking for is [expert witness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_witness)

Comment: What "translator" did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a trial, an expert who gives evidence, such as whether a bullet comes from a particular gun, is called an "expert witness".

An expert witness might be a forensic scientist who is presenting DNA evidence, or a ballistics expert, or even a psychologist who can give a present a psychological profile of a defendant.